# Django - get model object attributes from ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I have a ModelFormSet:

```
TransactionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Transaction, exclude=("",))
```

With this model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    date = models.DateField()
    payee = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    outflow = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    inflow = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    cleared = models.BooleanField()
```

And this is the template:

```
{% for transaction in transactions %}
<ul>
    {% for field in transaction %}
        {% ifnotequal field.label 'Id' %}
        {% ifnotequal field.value None %}
            {% ifequal field.label 'Categories' %}
                // what do i do here?
            {% endifequal %}
            <li>{{ field.label}}: {{ field.value }}</li>
        {% endifnotequal %}
        {% endifnotequal %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The view:

```
def transactions_on_account_view(request, account_id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        transactions = TransactionFormSet(queryset=Transaction.objects.for_account(account_id))
        context = {"transactions":transactions}
        return render(request, "transactions/transactions_for_account.html", context)
```

I want to list all the Transaction information on a page.
How can I list the "account" property of Transaction and the "categories"?
Currently the template shows only their id, I want to get a nice representation for the user (preferrably from their **str**() method).

The only way I can see that would work is to iterate over the FormSet, get the Ids of the Account and Category objects, get the objects by their Id and store the information I want in a list and then pull it from there in the template, but that seems rather horrible to me.

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. What are all those nested ifequal/ifnotequal statements for? And `__str__` is the default representation for a modelmultiplechoicefield, which is what your many-to-many field will use on the form; have you tried just `{{ field }}`?

Comment: {{ field }} for categories gives me a choice box, for account a dropdown of different accounts, I want to show just the selected account (without a dropbox) and just the selected category (without a choice). I don't want to input any changes / information, I just want to show all the attributes of Transaction as text.

Comment: So why are you using forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I figured it out that what I was doing was pretty dumb and pointless.

This works:

1) Get all Transaction objects

```
transactions = Transaction.objects.for_account(account_id)
```

2) Pass to template

```
context = {"transactions":transactions,}
    return render(request, "transactions/transactions_for_account.html", context)
```

3) Access attributes, done

```
  {% for transaction in transactions %}
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">{{ transaction.account }}</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">{{ transaction.categories }}</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">{{ transaction.date }}</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">{{ transaction.payee }}</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">{{ transaction.comment }}</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">{{ transaction.outflow }}</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">{{ transaction.inflow }}</td>
    <td class="tg-6k2t">{{ transaction.cleared }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```